# MDC Web Datatable component - Paging, Sorting

Tags: material-design

I am new to Material Design, Trying to implement paging and sorting for the MDC web datatable component. I have managed to achieve sorting but when the table is redrawn it looks weird

**Before Sorting**

[image: Before sorting]

---

**After Sorting**
[image: After sorting]

Comment: Code pen link for the demo: https://codepen.io/manik11/pen/podddqY?editors=1010